# Does Android 4.0 (ICS) support Kannada Font?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, fonts

I am developing one regional language kannada news app,in which my problem is that,in 2.2 and 2.3 the app does not suppport kannada fonts whereas 3.0 supports kannada font.

One month back I heard that Android would provide all 3.0 features in 4.0

So my question to enthusiasts is that could any one help me about how to go with the kannada font?