# Font rendering problem in ICS 4.0.4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, localization, fonts

I'm trying to get Kannada language support on my phone. I've rooted my Sony Xperia Neo L which is running ICS 4.0.4 and installed Kannada font in system/fonts. The problem is, all the other indic fonts like tamil, bengali, devanagari, hindi are rendering perfectly but not Kannada. I've added the Kannada font in fallback_fonts.xml file. Is that a font problem?

Comment: How is this different than [your previous question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43998/indic-fontkannada-is-not-rendering-properly-in-android-ics)?

Comment: You're not the only one trying to figure it out: [Does Android 4.0 (ICS) support Kannada Font?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17559)

Comment: Sorry but i'm kinda desparate :P

Comment: And the weird problem is, the font in the title of the article is rendering properly. But when i click on it to read the full story, the font in the body of the article isn't rendering properly.